# Compression GZIP error when trying to open FITS image in another directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, compression, astropy, fits

I am trying to analyze the data of a FITS image that is located in a different directory than that of my python program. The image is not compressed, but I receive the following error after this line of code:

```
from astropy.io import fits
img_file = '/home/rest/of/path/my_image.fits'
img_data = fits.getdata(img_file)
```

Error:

```
    img_data = fits.getdata(img_file)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/astropy-1.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/astropy/io/fits/convenience.py", line 208, in getdata
    data = hdu.data
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/astropy-1.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/astropy/utils/decorators.py", line 722, in __get__
    val = self.fget(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/astropy-1.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/astropy/io/fits/hdu/compressed.py", line 1368, in data
    data = compression.decompress_hdu(self)
ValueError: Unrecognized compression type: GZIP_2
```

I think it must be the path specification that is causing the error, since when I ran it earlier within all the same directories and only specified the file name, it worked. I also read in another question that this path specification should work. How can I successfully get the data from an image in another directory?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to upload the fits file somewhere and include a link to it in your question (so others can try to reproduce the problem)?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upload the same FITS file since it cannot be released to the public. However, I can provide some more info after some more tests: The above problem occurs when I run the code in a remote server, which runs python 2.7. However, on my personal computer which runs python 3.6, I do not get this error.

Comment: The difference may also be due to the fact that the two sysem are likely running different versions of `astropy.io`. Regardless, you can test your theory about the use of full file paths causing the problem by using `os.chdir()` to change the current working directory to the directory the file is in before calling `getdata()` with only the file's name. If that avoids the error, you have also discovered a workaround (that will work even when not really necessary).

Comment: Reinforcing my observation about the possibility of different versions of `astropy.io` being used, from the error message in your question it looks like `astropy-1.3` is being used, which is an older version (the latest looks like its currently 3.1).

Comment: Normally the working directory from which you run a script shouldn't matter, so you must be doing something (subtly) wrong, but it's hard to say what. What is the filename of the script you're running? Do note that by default if you have a file named like `foo.py` in your current directory, then statements like `import foo` may import the your `foo.py` rather than some globally installed "correct" foo module. This "shadowing" of module names is a useful but annoying newbie trap in Python.

Comment: And yes, astropy 1.3 is very old